# 日付が指定の形式で入力されているかの判定について

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

jspのテキストボックスに入力された日付を
(●●●●/●●/●●)の形式で指定したいと思います。

jspで入力された値をservletで受け取り、
その値をSimpleDateFormatを用いて
(yyyy/MM/dd)で判定したいです。

(yyyy/MM/dd)形式なら値をjspに返し、
そうでなければエラーメッセージを返そうと考えています。

どうすれば上記の方法で判定ができるでしょうか。
お手数ですが宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleDateFormatを使いたいのであれば、Servletの実装はこんな感じでしょうか。

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    sdf.setLenient(false);
    String inputDate = req.getParameter("inputDate");
    if(inputDate == null || inputDate.trim().length() == 0){
        req.setAttribute("errorMessage", "date is required");
    } else {
        try {
            sdf.parse(inputDate);
            req.setAttribute("inputDate", inputDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            req.setAttribute("errorMessage", "date format is invalid");
        }
    }
    // ...(以下略)...
}
```

`setLenient(false)`を設定することで、形式だけでなく、うるう年などの日付の妥当性チェックもするようになります。

Comment: そういうメソッドもあるんですね…勉強になりまりた！ありがとうございます！